# PowerApps to call Azure API App

Tags: api, azure, powerapps

I am new to PowerApps development. I am trying to connect PowerApps to my custom APIs (Azure app api) and getting results of "resource not found". I can call the api from browsers, postman no problem. The .json file I use for PowerApps is the same as the one I use for editor.swagger.io (for testing). I checked the log file of the application on azure, all of the requests from browsers logged but not the ones from PowerApps. My question is, how PowerApps calls APIs and what is the right format of the .json file used for PowerApps app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend trying again, we had a small issue on our backend that was causing some 404's at times. A fix for it has been deployed so you might see it work.

PowerApps uses Swagger to determine the shape of the REST api to be able to project those APIs into "formulas" that can be used easily in the client.

Also, for development/troubleshooting purposes I highly recommend using Fiddler to see exactly the REST call that PowerApps is doing and making sure the URL and parameters are correct. If not then look into your swagger definition and make sure there are no issues with the paths provided there.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check that your Azure App API has either:

1. The [PowerApps IP Addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/limits-and-config#ip-addresses) Whitelisted OR
2. If available, the "Allow Access to Azure Services" option toggled

[image]

When building Azure *SQL* backends for PowerApps, one of these paths must be followed.